# I'm not able to store the value from the drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code, when I run the code in the browser I'm not able to store value to the database I get from the drop down

I tried so many times but failed. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
public partial class UserBranchAdminProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{  
    public BLLCreateUser blbranchAdmin = new BLLCreateUser();
    public Branch branchdetails = new Branch();
    public BranchAdminDetails branchProfileDetails = new BranchAdminDetails();
}  

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        locationSelectDrop.DataSource = blbranchAdmin.getAllBranches();
        locationSelectDrop.DataTextField = "BranchLocation";
        locationSelectDrop.DataValueField = "BranchId";
        locationSelectDrop.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void submitProfileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     branchProfileDetails.userId = userIdText.Text;
     branchProfileDetails.branchLocation=locationSelectDrop.SelectedValue.ToString();                        
     branchProfileDetails.address = addressTextBox.Text;
     branchProfileDetails.phoneNo = phoneNoText.Text;
     branchProfileDetails.emailId = emailText.Text;
     BLLCreateUser bc = new BLLCreateUser();

     bool result = bc.insertBranchAdminProfileDetails(branchProfileDetails);

     if (result == true)
     {
         branchAdminProfileLabel.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

This is my html markup:

```
<td class="style1"> 
    <asp:Label ID="locationSelect" runat="server" Text="Enter Location"/>       
</td>
<td class="style2">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="locationSelectDrop" runat="server" style="marginleft:0px" 
            Width="178px"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

Comment: do you get any exception when you try to get the value ?

Comment: no i dont but when i check te database 0 is stored

Comment: Can you show us the **connection string** to your database?

Comment: Data Source=PC251181\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VRS_Testing;Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Are you actually even reading the value of locationSelectDrop in your BranchAdminDetails data object? :)

Comment: i did still it doesnt work when i check my database its still zero

Comment: Edited my answer, I don't see you filling your location in your data object anywhere in the posted code, have you missed it?

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you click submit button, **The Page_Load** will call, and in your code for every post back load event filling your drop down again and setting selected value as 0th position. so un-comment the check of IsPostback in **Page_Load** event and try to debug again.